# Why git range-diff does not show changes in commit?

Tags: git, git-range-diff

I compare two ranges:

[image]

**Why `git range-diff` does not show difference?** when `3a8c` and `2340` commits are different:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can see from the first image that `git range-diff` has decided that one patch was completely deleted in the original range, and a completely different *new* patch was supplied in its place.  This is what:

```
1:  2340cb53 <  -:  -------- Added placeholder for send form
-:  -------- >  1:  3a8c358d Added placeholder for send form
```

means.  Had Git decided that commits `2340cb53` and `3a8c358d` were different *forms* of the *same commit*, you would have seen:

```
1:  2340cb53 !  1:  3a8c358d Added placeholder for send form
```

You might next ask: *Why are these considered different patches, instead of a modification of a single patch?*  For that, we go to the **DESCRIPTION** section of [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-range-diff):<sup>1</sup>

> To that end, it first finds pairs of commits from both commit ranges
> that correspond with each other. Two commits are said to correspond
> when the diff between their patches (i.e. the author information, the
> commit message and the commit diff) is reasonably small compared to the
> patches' size.

Reading a bit further, into the **OPTIONS** section, we find:

> `--creation-factor=<percent>`
>
> Set the creation/deletion cost fudge factor to `<percent>`. Defaults
> to 60. Try a larger value if `git range-diff` erroneously considers a
> large change a total rewrite (deletion of one commit and addition
> of another), and a smaller one in the reverse case. See the
> ``Algorithm`` section below for an explanation why this is needed.

So you should re-run your command with a larger `--creation-factor`.

[image]

---

<sup>1</sup>Git documentation uses, here, the word "correspond" where I generally use the word "identity", referring to the philosophical problem of identity over time.  See [the Wikipedia entry for the Ship of Theseus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus).  This same problem crops up in simple commit-vs-commit diffs: how do we know that `some/path/to/file.ext` in commit *L* on the left is "the same" file as `different/path/to/name.extension` in commit *R* on the right?  The ultimate answer is always that we *don't* know this at all; we must use some method to make a guess.  For file-vs-file, as in the commit-vs-commit case, Git's primary method of guessing is to use the two files' path names.  For range-vs-range, that method does not work.

Comment: Would be nice to have an option for git. To show changes for same commits (when text is compared and it is similar, or similar 60%, in case when commit message is changes a bit)